# Assuming the wing is strong enough to handle the forces, would allocating wing area towards the tip of a creature's wings help with flapping flight?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, flight, bio-mechanics

When it comes to pushing against fluids (such as water and air) you gotta get speed, demon speed! Speed is what we need! We need greasy-fast speed! It's rather apparent that slow-moving objects tend to meet less air-resistance than faster ones. Birds use said resistance to push against the air and go upwards. Well, there's more to it but that's the basic idea.

For powered fliers (which are more-or-less the bane of my existence), their wingtips travel the longest distance under the same angular velocity, i.e: they're the fastest part of the wing and thus have the most potential to generate force...

Yet, out of all the wing shapes I could find, only Alduin's (see pic related) seem to even attempt to get broader towards the tip.

While one explanation could be that such adaptation never evolved, or had the chance to evolve; it could also have required stronger bones and skin to withstand the forces involved.

**Or alternatively, I missed something that would have revealed that this wing-design was terribly ineffective.**

I honestly don't know. I already justified most of my dragons' characteristics with biogenic super materials, **I could wave my hands and say that dragon wings can take a lot of stress without being heavier, but would that make this wing design superior to others at force-production during flapping flight?**

[image]

Comment: one thing that might be an issue is torsion strain---it'll be hard to keep the wingtips at the right angle if they aren't anchored to the body by the rest of the wing

Comment: Um... You put science based and then include a picture of  a dragon that, at least on Earth, clearly cannot fly. Dragons require magic. Look at those feet and that tail. It would need much more wing area.

Comment: Also, in real birds, "assuming the wing is strong enough" is just wrong. Wings are a compromise among many factors: weight, strength, flight style, and a bunch of other things. For example, check out how bird bones are constructed to be light.

Comment: @puppetsock I've put in a picture where the shape of Alduin's wings clearly shows, everything else is irrelevant.

Comment: *"Only Alduin's [wings] seem to even attempt to get broader towards the tip":* You didn't look in the right places. Dragons are fictional, but helicopters are real. [Kamov Ka-52](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ka-52_at_MAKS-2009.jpg). [Mil Mi-8](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Mil_Mi-8P,_Baltic_Airlines_(cropped).jpg). [Mil Mi-28](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:VVS_100th_IMG_0063_(cropped).jpg). [Sikorsky S-64](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Erickson_Air-Crane_(N6962R)_Sikorsky_S-64E_departing_Wagga_Wagga_Airport_(cropped).jpg).

Comment: @puppetsock I also said that this design was supposed to increase the force produced during flapping flight and large fliers tend to have a lower flap amplitude. What I forgot was the weight, but that's fixed now.

Comment: The fact that no Earthly life form seems to have evolved anything like this, despite considerable pressure for optimization (and many examples of near-optimum evolved wings) might be something of a hint.

Comment: @AlexP: But those helicoptor rotors DON'T get broader towards the tips.  They have a narrow shaft near the hub to facilitate the mechanical linkage, then are either the same width all the way to the tip, or get narrower.  (Not to mention that you really don't want your rotor blades to flap much :-))  You can see something similar in for instance dragonfly or butterfly wings, where the wing has a narrow part close to the body, then get wider before tapering towards the tip: https://phys.org/news/2018-09-dragonfly-wings-patterns.html

Comment: "Assuming the wing is strong enough to handle the forces"  assuming such wings would be shapped like oars.

Comment: @AlexP Helicopters  use the rotors to hold them in the air by the vertical component of "centrifugal" force, if you were to jack up a stationery helicopter by the rotors, the rotors would collapse. I guess this gets back at the "assuming the wings are strong enough" assumption.

Comment: Wasn't there an article that basically explained using weighted wristbands was essentially the best way to get a shoulder injury when exercising. I am willing to bet wings would follow suit with all that extra tip mass.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the dragon wings you show are based on exaggerated bat-wings

[image]

If we look at the following drawing of a bat, we can see see how it is similar in anatomy to the dragon

[image]

In fact, I have edited this to make it much more like the dragon's anatomy.

[image]

My suggestion is that you could imagine a bat in the above form being able to fly although it might be considerably disabled.

---

**Speed of flight**

There is a claim here that, quote:

[Brazilian free-tailed bats may have achieved speeds of up to 160 kilometres per hour in level flight, which would make them faster than any bird.](https://www.newscientist.com/article/2112044-speedy-bat-flies-at-160kmh-smashing-bird-speed-record/)

[image]

However those wings appear to taper towards the ends, as do the wings of many fast-flying birds such as swifts.

---

This may also be contradicted by the speeds shown in the following table. It seems to contradict the claims about the bat being faster. I think more research would be needed on both counts.

[**List of birds by flight speed**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_birds_by_flight_speed)

Comment: Holy ****, this resignifies the expression "bat out of hell"!

Comment: However, this doesn't answer the OP's question. Unless what you're explaining is that the very opposite of what Meph is looking for is superior? (He asked if paddle-shaped wings would in any way be superior....)

Comment: @JBH - Ah sorry. I should have been more explicit. Yes my intention was to say that paddle-shaped wings aren't good for speed (the requirement for which was emphasised strongly in the first sentences of the question). I'll add some more to my answer about this.

Comment: That's cheating! I said allocating wing area, not decreasing it! It's gonna have trouble flying because you increased its wing loading!